# What's an algorithm to retrieve values for a week to date calculation

Tags: c#, algorithm

The algorithm needs to accept a date and then get values for each day from Monday until the date inputted.

Edit:

In a database I have values stored for every day of the week. I want to be able to accept a date parameter and then retrieve a list of values from Monday of the week that date parameter falls in until the date parameter. e.g 5th May 2011. Retrieve values for each day from Monday 2nd May upto Thursday 5th May.

Comment: What is the starting point, Can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I think `DateTime.DayOfWeek` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    static IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysFromMonday(DateTime d)
    {
        var diff = d.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
        var monday = d.AddDays(-diff).Date;
        for (var day = monday; day < d; day = day.AddDays(1))
            yield return day;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var DateInput = DateTime.Now;

var FromMondayToDate =
    from dateindex in Enumerable.Range(-7, 7)
    let TestDate = DateInput.AddDays(dateindex)
    let Monday = DateInput.AddDays(-(int)DateInput.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Monday)
    where TestDate >= Monday
    select TestDate;
```

EDIT: Looking at your edit, my answer gets you part-way there. You now have a list of dates to retrieve values for. You now have to query the database, or ideally run the query above on the database either by writing equivilent SQL, or by using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: this seems mostly correct, but a little sloppy. I would like its Linq qualities better if it enumerated only the days it needed rather than filtering down a two week range. also, it seems like it would return dates in the future

Comment: @Merlyn, It only filters the 1 week range, from 7 says ago, until today (the 2nd parameter is the count, not the upper limit). It won't return future dates, the enumerable goes from -7 to 0, not from -7 to +7.

Comment: oh, thats right. it seems it should give the correct final range then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public List<DateTime> CreateDateList(DateTime inputDate)
{ 
    List<DateTime> mondayList = new List<DateTime>();
    while(inputDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        mondayList.Add(inputDate);
        inputDate = inputDate.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return mondayList;
}
```

Depending you need to forward or backwards change the AddDays paramter